# jQuery output after the script

Tags: jquery

My jQuery script creates a form. I need the form to appear **just before** the script :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="..."></script>
//the form appears here...
```

This previous line will appear on various sites so I cannot insert/append.. it to an element `$('element')...` it would need to be : `$('current script').prepend('...')`

I would like users to be able to insert the script where they want the form to appear

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is this script tag placed in the body then? I wouldn't insert form elements if the script is in the head...

Comment: I would like users to be able to insert the script where they want the form to appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question right...

```
$('script[src="your/path"]').after(element);
```

where element is what you're inserting.

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/ 
http://api.jquery.com/after/

Answer (score 0):

Usually you're using `document.write()` to achieve this(google is doing this for example when inserting pageads)

Answer (score 0):

You can insert a placeholder with `document.write()` and the use jQuery to place the form into the palceholder. So your script could look like this:

```
document.write('<div id="placeholderForForm"></div>");

$('#placeholderForForm').xx(...);
```

Even easier is probably to insert large pieces of the form with `document.write()`.